# Contraint Failed Exception

Tags: ios, swift, earlgrey

My Earlgrey tests are working fine on iPhone 6s plus simulator, but when I run the same test on iPhone 6 simulator, it gives `constraintFailedException`.

This is my code:

```
EarlGrey.select(elementWithMatcher: grey_accessibilityID("passwordTextField"))
    .atIndex(1).perform(grey_typeText(Validation.default.password))
```

here is the exception

> Exception Details: [ { "Description" : "Cannot perform action due to constraint(s) failure.", "Error Domain" : "com.google.earlgrey.ElementInteractionErrorDomain", "Error Code" : "1", "File Name" : "GREYBaseAction.m", "Function Name" : "-[GREYBaseAction satisfiesConstraintsForElement:error:]", "Line" : "66", "TestCase Class" : "GalaxyTests.UITests", "TestCase Method" : "testExample" } ]

Comment: What was the error that you were seeing? The logs show what was missing from the query. It could be that the element was unavailable or wasn't fully interactable().

Comment: maybe the password field is not fully visible hence the interactable() matcher fails.

Comment: Exception Details: [
  {
    "Description" : "Cannot perform action due to constraint(s) failure.",
    "Error Domain" : "com.google.earlgrey.ElementInteractionErrorDomain",
    "Error Code" : "1",
    "File Name" : "GREYBaseAction.m",
    "Function Name" : "-[GREYBaseAction satisfiesConstraintsForElement:error:]",
    "Line" : "66",
    "TestCase Class" : "GalaxyTests.UITests",
    "TestCase Method" : "testExample"
  }
]